# Editing Dropdownlist problem in Pop up window in telerik razor controls

Tags: c#, telerik

I have created dropdownlist in Telerik Razor Control. Now the problem is while i click on Edit button gridview one pop up window will come  and i am getting dropdownlist filled with values..bt i am not getting selected dropdownlist value... i mean i am not getting particular value of selected records..its giving all the values in dropdownlist like what we are getting while we click on add button...so can anyone please help me out

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Are you using Telerik's ComboBox and Grid controls for ASP.NET MVC? Perhaps if you provide some code we can better help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is a year late but I ll post it anyway.
For MVC : In your grid, define the dropdownlist with the foreigkey for the field as such :

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<YOURModel>()
                    .Name("yournameGrid")
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                      columns.Bound(device => device.Id),
                      columns.ForeignKey(model => model.HeadSetId, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["headsets"], "Id", "Name");
                    })
                     .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .Ajax()
                        .Model(model =>
                        {
                          model.Id(device => device.Id);
                          model.Field(d => d.HeadSetId).DefaultValue(ViewData["defaultHeadSetId"]);
                         })
                        .Read(read => read.Action("FunctionHere", "ControllerHere"))
       )
```

Then in your controller define the data for the dropdownlist in the function that is loading the view for the grid :

```
  PopulateDropdownList();
```

This function would look something like this :

```
    private void PopulateDropdownList()
    {
        var data= db.HeadSets.ToList()
                    .OrderBy(h => h.Name)
                    .Select(h => new HeadSet
                    {
                        Id = h.Id,
                        Name = h.Name
                    });
        ViewData["headsets"] = headSets;
        int hsID = 0;
        if (headSets.Count() > 0)
        {
            hsID = headSets.First().Id;
        }
        ViewData["defaultHeadSetId"] = hsID;
    }
```

In the pop up (template) define the DropdownList:

```
   @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.HeadsetId)
                .Name("HeadSetId") // THE NAME OF THE WIDGET MUST BE THE SAME AS THE PROPERTY!.
                .HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "margin-left:15px;" })
                .DataValueField("Id") // The value of the dropdown is taken from the item's Id property.
                .DataTextField("Name") // The text of the items is taken from the item's Name property.
                .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["headsets"])// A list of all headsets which is populated in the controller.

            )
```

This should correctly bind the selected value of the record to the dropdownlist.